# Ошибка no method declared with objective-c selector

Tags: swift

На строчку выдает ошибку, как исправить? `no method declared with objective-c selector "resetAction"`

```html
if let resetButton = menu.subviews.last as? UIButton {
            resetButton.addTarget(self, action: Selector("resetAction"), forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
        }
        view.addSubview(menu)
        func resetAction() {
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В swift2.2/xcode7.3 объявление селекторов поменяли.

Вам вместо `Selector("resetAction")` надо писать `#selector(self.resetAction)`

Comment: Если пишу так, то выдает ошибку "Value of type 'Scene' has no member 'resetAction'"

Comment: ну видимо вместо self надо что то другое (имя класса, в котором есть resetAction)